# EventEmitter emits data but not event

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, event-binding

I am struggling in a particular scenario. Here is how my Parent and Child class looks

```
export class ChildComponent{
    .....
    @Output select: EventEmiiter<SomeType> = new EventEmmiter();
    ....
    ....

    methodWhichEmits(){
          this.select.emit(objectOf_SomeType);
    }
}




 export class ParentComponent{

        onSelect(emittedObject){
              //perform some logic
              event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }



 Parent Template
   <child (select)="onSelect($event)"></child>
```

My understanding(being new to angular) is that an event is emitted from child and caught in parent
and then logic is performed in onSelect parent's method on the emitted event (event binding).

But the problem is that the parameter of parent method is not an event but the object of SomeType passed from child. I want to receive an event in my parent method and access the data emitted from child using the event object (something like event.target.value) because I need the event object to invoke stopPropagation() upon.

Even though the code works fine but test case fails (on topPropagation()) as instead of event an object of SomeType is received in parent's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EventEmitter is not an HTML event but an extension of a Subject so it will only send a event with a value

Answer (score 2):

If you could forgo `SomeType` type, one workaround would be to call the `stopPropagation()` in the child component and send in the `target` as the event parameter. Try the following

Child component

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() select = new EventEmitter();

  handleSomething(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.methodWhichEmits(event.target);
  }

  methodWhichEmits(value) {
    this.select.emit(value)
  }
}
```

Parent component - Template

```html
<app-child (select)=onSelect($event)></app-child>
```

Parent component - Controller

```js
onSelect(target: any) {
  // handle target  
}
```

If you try to send the `event` directly as the emitter value, there might some unwanted side effects due to event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Anguar events are not like the native ones. They are just object as you noticed, they don't propagate, and they can't be cancelled.